# Loop to test HTTP Status Code?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script to test several internal URL (around 15-20 URL) from an external Server which looks like this(i changed the URL to some random url like youtube etc. for this post):

```
#!/bin/bash 
code=`curl -i -L -s "https://www.youtube.com/ https://www.google.com/ https://twitter.com/?lang=de| grep 200` 
if [ -z "$code" ]
then
exit 0 
else
exit 1
fi
```

I want to put all the URL in a Variable(if possible) and then for example do curl -i -L -s $ALLURL and grep for HTTP 200 or put them somehow in a list (i think there is something called "table" in Linux(idk?) so i can then do curl -i -L -s (all the URL´s).

If one of URL`s gets a HTTP 200 then it should exit with status code 1 (exit 1) and if not it should just do exit 0

Why do i want to change my script even tho it is working? Because it can be a bit confusing to remove or check if one URL is missing when they are all in one single Line.

i would like to have the URL like this in the script:

```
https://URL1 
https://URL2 
https://URL3
...
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: "Why do i want to change my script even tho it is working?" I don't see a working script here. The code you pasted certainly doesn't do what you want it to do ("If one of URLs gets a HTTP 200 then it should exit with status code 1 (exit 1) and if not it should just do exit 0")

Comment: For everyone starting on Bash scripting, I'll recommend [this online course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT98CRl2KxKGj-VKtApD8-zCqSaN2mD4w) to get you started.